# Is it possible to google for C without getiing C++ in the results?

Tags: c

I know this isn't really a programming question but I wondered if anyone knew if there was a way of constructing a google query that returned results about the C language without results for C++.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your normal search value and add -c++ and -cpp(including the minus symbol)

Comment: oh that was simpler than I thought, in previous experiments google appeared to ignore + symbols (and thus ++) as a search term, but appears I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: c programming -"c++"

Appears to work on quick inspection.

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Google search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=can+you+ban+words+when+googling&client=firefox-a&hs=oxb&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=fflb&tbas=0&biw=1288&bih=831&hl=en)

The advanced options for Google allow you to ban words, so you can just ban "C++" and whatever else you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! 
`c -++`

for example : searching for new york without hotels

`new york -hotel`